# Display discussion replies below discussion view page

Tags: discussion-board

Is it possible to display the discussion replies in the discussion view page? I mean when I display the discussion display form, I want to view all the discussion replies for that discussion.

Comment: The actual replies or just a counting of how many replies there is in the discussion?

Comment: The actual replies